# ～にけがをする versus ～をけがする

Tags: grammar, word-choice, particles

> 私は左手にけがをした。
>   私は左手をけがした。

Are both correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are both correct.

As you can see in [this J-J dictionary entry](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E6%80%AA%E6%88%91-489585#E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.9E.97.20.E7.AC.AC.E4.B8.89.E7.89.88), [怪我]{けが} can be *a noun* and *a する-verb*, so you can say for example:

> 「彼は事故で腕**に**怪我**を**した。」<sub>(← 怪我 is a noun)</sub>
>   「彼は事故で腕**を**怪我した。」<sub>(← 怪我 is a suru-verb)</sub>
>   "He injured his arm in an/the accident."

The only difference that I can feel is... the latter sounds just a little bit more casual/less formal than the former.

Answer (score 1):

"私は左手にけがをした" means that your left hand was injured.  "私は左手をけがした" means you injured your left hand. Similar meaning, left hand is injured in both, but the focus of blame is different. Both are correct.

Comment: They are different, though the difference is subtle. 
I think that you have delicate sensibilities. I agree with your understanding of the difference. (+1 upvote)

Answer (score 1):

Yes both are correct, and have the same meaning. Unless otherwise specified, both usually mean your left hand was injured in an accident.

Comment: あぁっ・・なるとさんの回答があったのね・・ Naruto-san beat me to it...

Comment: @Schokolade 詳しい回答お疲れ様です！ｗ